# Android Ribbon menu using fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, scrollview, ribbon, android-listfragment

I did a coding for ribbon menu using horizontal scrollview. my code is given below:

```
public class HorzScrollWithListMenuActivity extends Activity {


        MyHorizontalScrollView scrollView;
        View menu;
        View app;
        ImageView btnSlide;
        boolean menuOut = false;
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        int btnWidth;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(HorzScrollWithListMenuActivity.this);
            scrollView = (MyHorizontalScrollView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.horz_scroll_with_list_menu, null);
            setContentView(scrollView); 

            menu = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horz_scroll_menu, null);
            app = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horz_scroll_app, null);
            ViewGroup tabBar = (ViewGroup) app.findViewById(R.id.tabBar);

            ListView listView = (ListView) app.findViewById(R.id.list);
            ViewUtils.initListView(this, listView, "Item ", 50, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

            listView = (ListView) menu.findViewById(R.id.list);
            ViewUtils.initListView(this, listView, "Menu ", 30, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

            btnSlide = (ImageView) tabBar.findViewById(R.id.BtnSlide);
            btnSlide.setOnClickListener(new ClickListenerForScrolling(scrollView, menu,app));

            final View[] children = new View[] { menu, app };

            // Scroll to app (view[1]) when layout finished.
            int scrollToViewIdx = 1;
            scrollView.initViews(children, scrollToViewIdx, new SizeCallbackForMenu(btnSlide));
        }

        /**
         * Helper for examples with a HSV that should be scrolled by a menu View's width.
         */
        static class ClickListenerForScrolling implements OnClickListener {
            HorizontalScrollView scrollView;
            View menu;
            View app;
            /**
             * Menu must NOT be out/shown to start with.
             */
            boolean menuOut = false;

            public ClickListenerForScrolling(HorizontalScrollView scrollView, View menu, View app) {
                super();
                this.scrollView = scrollView;
                this.menu = menu;
                this.app=app;
            }

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context = menu.getContext();
                String msg = "Slide " + new Date();
                Toast.makeText(context, msg, 1000).show();
                System.out.println(msg);


                int menuWidth = menu.getMeasuredWidth();

                // Ensure menu is visible
                menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (!menuOut) {
                    // Scroll to 0 to reveal menu
                    int left = 0;
                    scrollView.smoothScrollTo(left, 0);

                } else {
                    // Scroll to menuWidth so menu isn't on screen.
                    int left = menuWidth;
                    scrollView.smoothScrollTo(left, 0);

                }
                menuOut = !menuOut;
                if(v.isPressed())
                {
                    v.setClickable(false);

                }


            }
        }

        /**
         * Helper that remembers the width of the 'slide' button, so that the 'slide' button remains in view, even when the menu is
         * showing.
         */
        static class SizeCallbackForMenu implements SizeCallback {
            int btnWidth;
            View btnSlide;

            public SizeCallbackForMenu(View btnSlide) {
                super();
                this.btnSlide = btnSlide;
            }

            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                btnWidth = btnSlide.getMeasuredWidth();
                System.out.println("btnWidth=" + btnWidth);
            }

            public void getViewSize(int idx, int w, int h, int[] dims) {
                dims[0] = w;
                dims[1] = h;
                final int menuIdx = 0;
                if (idx == menuIdx) {
                    dims[0] = w - btnWidth;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**MyHorizontalScrollView.java**

```
public class MyHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView {
    public MyHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyHorizontalScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    void init(Context context) {
        // remove the fading as the HSV looks better without it
        setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
        setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
    }

    /**
     * @param children
     *            The child Views to add to parent.
     * @param scrollToViewIdx
     *            The index of the View to scroll to after initialisation.
     * @param sizeCallback
     *            A SizeCallback to interact with the HSV.
     */
    public void initViews(View[] children, int scrollToViewIdx, SizeCallback sizeCallback) {
        // A ViewGroup MUST be the only child of the HSV
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getChildAt(0);

        // Add all the children, but add them invisible so that the layouts are calculated, but you can't see the Views
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            children[i].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            parent.addView(children[i]);
        }

        // Add a layout listener to this HSV
        // This listener is responsible for arranging the child views.
        OnGlobalLayoutListener listener = new MyOnGlobalLayoutListener(parent, children, scrollToViewIdx, sizeCallback);
        getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Do not allow touch events.
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Do not allow touch events.
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * An OnGlobalLayoutListener impl that passes on the call to onGlobalLayout to a SizeCallback, before removing all the Views
     * in the HSV and adding them again with calculated widths and heights.
     */
    class MyOnGlobalLayoutListener implements OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        ViewGroup parent;
        View[] children;
        int scrollToViewIdx;
        int scrollToViewPos = 0;
        SizeCallback sizeCallback;

        /**
         * @param parent
         *            The parent to which the child Views should be added.
         * @param children
         *            The child Views to add to parent.
         * @param scrollToViewIdx
         *            The index of the View to scroll to after initialisation.
         * @param sizeCallback
         *            A SizeCallback to interact with the HSV.
         */
        public MyOnGlobalLayoutListener(ViewGroup parent, View[] children, int scrollToViewIdx, SizeCallback sizeCallback) {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.children = children;
            this.scrollToViewIdx = scrollToViewIdx;
            this.sizeCallback = sizeCallback;
        }

        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // System.out.println("onGlobalLayout");

            final HorizontalScrollView me = MyHorizontalScrollView.this;

            // The listener will remove itself as a layout listener to the HSV
            me.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

            // Allow the SizeCallback to 'see' the Views before we remove them and re-add them.
            // This lets the SizeCallback prepare View sizes, ahead of calls to SizeCallback.getViewSize().
            sizeCallback.onGlobalLayout();

            parent.removeViewsInLayout(0, children.length);

            final int w = me.getMeasuredWidth();
            final int h = me.getMeasuredHeight();

            // System.out.println("w=" + w + ", h=" + h);

            // Add each view in turn, and apply the width and height returned by the SizeCallback.
            int[] dims = new int[2];
            scrollToViewPos = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                sizeCallback.getViewSize(i, w, h, dims);
                // System.out.println("addView w=" + dims[0] + ", h=" + dims[1]);
                children[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                parent.addView(children[i], dims[0], dims[1]);
                if (i < scrollToViewIdx) {
                    scrollToViewPos += dims[0];
                }
            }

            // For some reason we need to post this action, rather than call immediately.
            // If we try immediately, it will not scroll.
            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    me.scrollBy(scrollToViewPos, 0);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Callback interface to interact with the HSV.
     */
    public interface SizeCallback {
        /**
         * Used to allow clients to measure Views before re-adding them.
         */
        public void onGlobalLayout();

        /**
         * Used by clients to specify the View dimensions.
         * 
         * @param idx
         *            Index of the View.
         * @param w
         *            Width of the parent View.
         * @param h
         *            Height of the parent View.
         * @param dims
         *            dims[0] should be set to View width. dims[1] should be set to View height.
         */
        public void getViewSize(int idx, int w, int h, int[] dims);
    }
}
```

**ViewUtils.java**

```
public class ViewUtils {
    private ViewUtils() {
    }


    public static void initListView(Context context, ListView listView, String prefix, int numItems, int layout) {
        // By using setAdpater method in listview we an add string array in list.
        String[] arr = new String[numItems];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = prefix + (i + 1);
        }
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, layout, arr));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Context context = view.getContext();
                String msg = "item[" + position + "]=" + parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(context, msg, 1000).show();
                System.out.println(msg);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Please tell me how to give swipe option.

**How to do the same project(Ribbon menu) using fragments?**

Comment: buhaha thakarthu machaaa...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActionBarSherlock is very useful library to build that kinds of apps,

Please check first this library,
http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Then checkout this project,
https://bitbucket.org/owentech/abstabsviewpager/

I hope it will help to solve your problem.

Happy coding...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got the output.