# Android Ribbon menu without fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, ribbon

How can i implement **facebook like sliding menu without using fragments**? I referred github, but they also using fragments for this. please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented ribbon menu without using fragments. U can refer this link [Android Ribbon menu using fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525267). In that I provided the codes for ribbon menu without using fragments. Please check it out. It will really helps you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I reccomend using this library : https://github.com/bk138/LibSlideMenu. It does not use fragments and is really useful.